# Why does this jQuery code work fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not IE9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

If I take away the `> option` it works but obviously this does not yield the
desired effect. I have tried `$('.ProductsInCatList option')` and `$('.ProductsInCatList').find('option')` to no avail. Either of which work fine
in Firefox and Chrome. I just want the code to execute when the option is selected
from a Multiselect list. Using JQuery 1.6.4. **Update: Ok, so apparently IE9 does not work with click events for option element, shame and here I thought I did away with button controls for this**

```
 $('.ProductsInCatList')
        .delegate("option","click", function () {}); //<-- Also does not work
```

jQuery

```
$('.ProductsInCatList > option').live("click", function () {
    var option = $(this).clone();

    alert('works');

    var slist = $(this).parent().prev('.SelectedList');
    option.appendTo(slist);
    $(this).detach();
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="ListWrapper">
    <div class="CatHeading">Processor</div> 
        <input type="hidden" class="colindex" name="index" value="a1" />
        <input class="ItemCount" name="[a1].ItemCount" type="hidden" value="0" />
        <input class="ListID" name="[a1].ListID" type="hidden" value="1" />

        <select class="SelectedList" multiple="multiple" name="[a1].SelectedList"></select> 

        <select class="ProductsInCatList" id="ProcessorMainList" multiple="multiple" name="ProcessorMainList">
            <option value="6">Intel 2nd Gen Core i7 2600 Socket 1155 Processor </option>
            <option value="8">Intel 2nd Gen Core i5 2500 Socket 1155 Processor</option>
            <option value="44">Intel Core i7-2700 </option>
            <option value="45">Intel Core i5-2400 </option>
            <option value="60">i3-2100T</option>
            <option value="3">Intel Core i7 950 Socket 1366 Processor </option>
            <option value="4">Intel Core i7 930 Socket 1366 Processor </option>
            <option value="37">Intel Xeon X5690</option>
            <option value="38">Intel Xeon X5870</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gdoron/XXQpu/)

Comment: Could you also post your HTML so we can see what class names relate to what elements.

Comment: It should be noted that `live` is deprecated since `JQuery 1.4`, We are on `JQuery 1.7.1` this days...

Comment: have you tried without space:'.ProductsInCatList>option'?

Comment: @BiAiB. It should be with space. [docs](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

Comment: @gdoron: technically, it was depreciated in 1.7; *As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on()...*

Comment: I am using 1.6.4.... live is deprecated ? Interesting what's used instead ? Because if I don't use it in some instances I get nothing, since DOM hasn't been updated for the browser, at least that's what it seems like. With .on() nothing works in any browser.

Comment: @LaserBeak. `delegate` is better then `live`

Comment: For 1.6.4 you should be using `delegate` instead.

Comment: When trying without any (delegate/on/live) it still works in all browsers apart from IE9. Something to do with that  $('.ProductsInCatList > option') selector

Comment: @LaserBeak. I tried the selecor, It works fine in `IE`

Comment: @gdoron works fine with option ?

Comment: @gdoron I mean with option and click event

Comment: Nope sorry, I ended up with `change` event as @meze did.

Answer (score 3):

[IE and old version of Safari/Chrome doesn't support](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/11/bug-280-lack-of-events-for-options.html) all events for options, including click events.

Probably the best way is to use `onchange` for select:

```
$('body').delegate(".ProductsInCatList", "change", function () {
    var option = $(this).find(":selected")
    ...
});
```

The only difference is it will be trigger only when a user changes the selected option.

Comment: good catch sir. I hadn't realised even IE9 was still made of fail

Comment: Dang! Looks like there's no practical way. Also I am using a MultiSelect not just a drop down select list.

Comment: Didn't notice ;( Then only a button under select or if you really need it, check the selected options in this select every 1 second and update the another.

Comment: @meze changing Jquery version would have no effect either right? So it's basically an IE9 bug.

Comment: @LaserBeak think it won't help. Jquery is just a wrapper for javascript events and IE has no event for option element. Anyway your solution with click isn't very good, i can't select multiple items with one click (i mean with holding mouse pressed).

Comment: @meze you don't need to select multiple items. As soon as you click on any option it's copied over to the SelectedList and all those values in SelectedList are posted off when you click submit, irrespective whether selected or not thanks to some jquery magic.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach this might be to refactor your code. 
You narrowed it down to the selector - so how about something like this:

```
$('option.ProductsInCatListOption').live('click', function () {
    var option = $(this).clone();

    alert('works');

    var slist = $(this).parent().prev('.SelectedList');
    option.appendTo(slist);
    $(this).detach();
});
```

HTML:

```
    <select class="ProductsInCatList" 
            id="ProcessorMainList" 
            multiple="multiple" 
            name="ProcessorMainList">
        <option value="6" 
                class="ProductsInCatListOption">
          Intel 2nd Gen Core i7 2600 Socket 1155 Processor
        </option>
        <option value="8" 
                class="ProductsInCatListOption">
          Intel 2nd Gen Core i5 2500 Socket 1155 Processor
        </option>
        <!-- etc -->
    </select>
```

Just a pseudo example, but I think something like this should work.

Also I've never used live() or delegate() but here are the docs for delegate():

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Hope this helps.

UPDATE:
another approach might be to attach an event to all  elements and test when the event is fired to see if the click is for the element you want. It's horrible and I don't recommend you do it, but here's how:

```
$('option').click(function(e){
    if ($(this).parents().filter('.ProductsInCatList').length>0)
    {
        //this click came from an option which is a 
        //child of the select you are interested in
        var minime = $(this).clone();
        alert('boo!');
        $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

Comment: My option list is autogenerated, I am using an MVC helper (ASP.NET) I do not believe I can set classes on option element.

Comment: you could do it with jQuery I suppose - otherwise, you could do an event on *all* option elements and test for the parent. bit of a shotgun approach but I can't see another way given these restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I've always found .live() to be quite buggy - had all kinds of strange bugs related to scope

Provided .ProductsInCatList is present on page load the following is equivalent, and in my experience more reliable

```
$('.ProductsInCatList').delegate("option", "click", function () {
   //
});
```